# Angular: ERROR: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular

Using Angular 6 here. I have a setup as below:

AppComponent has a Child0Component.

Child0Component has a button which opens a modal loading Child1Component.

Finally, Child1Component has a Dropdown and Grid(table) of data.

While this flow works fine with no issues.

Now I wrapped the AppComponent around a form and did pass all the instance to the child component and add formcontrol name etc. But When I click my modal, it loads the Child1component and throws an error in the console as:

```
ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

ERROR
Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

Below is my relevant Code:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate [formGroup]="dataForm">
    <div class="row">     
      <child0-app  [dataForm]="dataForm"></child0-app>     
    </div>    
</form>
```

Below is my Child1Component select which I believe is throwing error because if I comment this it works fine:

```
 <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="dataForm" >
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Type:</label>
          <select class="form-control input-medium" name="type" formControlName="type"  (change)="onChangeType();">
            <option value=''>-- Select Type --</option>
            <option [ngValue]="d.Id" *ngFor="let d of types">
              {{d.Name}}
            </option>
          </select>
          </div>
```

I added form control to do some validations etc as I would be having more controls in my components.

Not sure what's missing here as I followed some tutorials and I believe did create this correctly.

I also created a demo as below:

Demo: https://angular-modal-form-control.stackblitz.io

Edit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-form-control

--Updated--

```
AppComponent TS
 public dataForm: FormGroup;  

  ngOnInit () { 
     this.dataForm = this.fb.group({});
  }

Child1Component TS

@Input() dataForm: FormGroup;
```

Comment: Can you post the ts, so we can see how you are initializing the form.

Comment: @EduardoVargas I have added relevant code. FYI I created the demo you can see the entire TS at:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-form-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 issues
first

1. you need to initial your form control like this

   this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
      type: new FormControl()
    });
2. You need to use `*ngIf` since you are passing your form cross components `<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="dataForm" *ngIf="dataForm" >` to make sure form not initial before component received the dataForm object from it's parent.

UPDATE EXAMPLE
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-form-control-yhcs9a?file=null)

UPDATED WORKING EXAMPLE:

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-form-control-yhcs9a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild0.component.ts)

Okay the idea you did , that you following this steps

- Create form in `app.component`
- Passing you for to `child0.component`
- then trigger event on click `(click)="openModal()"`
- you create bootstrap modal then pass data to that modal
- get data from backend then open the modal and pass the data from server
- **Missing** to pass the form data object `dataForm` to created modal.

Now your open modal method should do like this

```
openModal() {
this.appService.getAllData().subscribe((data: any[]) => {     

 const initialState = {
  data: data,
  ignoreBackdropClick: true,
  animated: true,
  keyboard: true,
  dataForm: this.dataForm,
  class: 'moal'
};

    this.modalRef = 
    this.modalService.show(Child1Component,{initialState});
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to pass the FOrm reference to your child component when you open the modal:

Child0Component:

```
 this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(Child1Component,
    { initialState: { data , dataForm: this.dataForm}, ignoreBackdropClick: true, animated: true, keyboard: true, class: 'modal' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in this Formgroup, you have defined the other controls like formControlName="type" , this also need to be defined in your TS file like below:

```
 dataForm : FormGroup;
  and in ngOnInit()
    this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    type: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
```

set it to null, if you don't want any value to be selected in dropdown on load

```
<select formControlName= "type"  class="form-control" (change)="selectOption($event.target.value);">
     <option value= "null" disabled selected>Select XXXX</option>
                      <option [value]="t.name" *ngFor="let t of typeList">
                            {{t.fname}} - {{t.description}}
                      </option>
                </select>
```